# subset a file just on one column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a tab delim file, I want to make a subset on the basis of column 2, choosing "A".

```
435  A  2   27.92464882 8.63E-07    1   752721
564  F  2   30.12532071 2.87E-07    1   798959
654  A  2   29.26089611 4.43E-07    3   838555
345  E  2   28.56723908 6.26E-07    6   846808
665  E  2   28.27577506 7.24E-07    3   854250
787  A  2   28.16226794 7.67E-07    4   861808
435  F  2   27.92464882 8.63E-07    1   752721
```

Output:

```
435  A  2   27.92464882 8.63E-07    1   752721
654  A  2   29.26089611 4.43E-07    3   838555
787  A  2   28.16226794 7.67E-07    4   861808
```

Comment: you can use `cat filename | grep -i a` also.

Comment: @AvinashRedy if the letter A is encountered anywhere else on the line, it will generate a false positive if you go with a simple `grep`

Comment: Ya but he didn't mentioned anything like that and he mentioned `choosing A`

Comment: @Mongrel If the OP later wants to choose `E`, then they'll get all data using your method.  Also, the `cat` is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F '\t' '$2 == "A" { print }' file
```

Or simply:

```
awk '$2=="A"' file
```

Comment: @ Lucas:     i am afraid this command is not working for my input files. This does not return anything.

Comment: Is the file tab delimited for sure? (Your example above is not) Can you put the file online somewhere? What does `grep $'^[^\t]*\tA' < file` give you(needs bash or zsh)?

Comment: Thanks for the help.. It is working now.. i just had to do this on my file sed -i 's/\r$//'.. its working :)

Comment: @1_CR not sure about your edit. Strictly speaking the `-F '\t'` is also not mandatory (the man page says the default FS is any amount of whitespace (and I think files can also be read without shell redirection). If we assume that the OP has little knowledge about awk it might be easier to understand the verbose version. But *I* learned something from you edit :)

Comment: @1_CR there's nothing wrong with being explicit in your code.  Having `{print}` is as valid and correct as not having it.  For teaching novices, being explicit is probably better because it's less surprising/confusing.  IMO Instead of editing the `{print}` from the original answer, it is better to add a comment pointing out that it's not necessary, thus providing a valuable educational experience for everyone who views the answer in future.

Comment: True true. I rolled back my edit